# Data updating even when not being updated when using android room

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-livedata

I have an ArrayList that should be updated whenever my livedata from database using [Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room) updates. But when i check its values before and after updating my list, the before list seems to be updated already and shows similar results compared to my list after actually updating it. And this only happens when i am updating my Subtasks column.

*Item*

```
@Entity(tableName = "items")
data class Item(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Int = 0,
    val title: String,
    val subtasks: ArrayList<Subtask> = ArrayList(),
    val notes: String = ""
) {
    fun getDetails(): String {
        var subtaskString = ""
        for (subtask in subtasks) {
            subtaskString += "(${subtask.title}: ${subtask.done}), "
        }
        return "id: ${id}\n" +
                "title: ${title}\n" +
                "subtasks: ${subtaskString}\n" +
                "notes: ${notes}\n"
    }
}
```

*DataViewModel*

```
val allItems: LiveData<List<Item>>
init {
    allItems= itemRepository.allItems
}

fun update(item: Item) = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    itemRepository.update(item)
}
```

*ItemRepository*

```
val allItems: LiveData<List<Item>> = itemDao.getAllItems()

fun update(item: Item) {
    itemDao.update(item)
}
```

*ItemDao*

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM items")
fun getAllItems(): LiveData<List<Item>>

@Update
fun update(item: Item)
```

*MyFragment*

```
val mList= ArrayList<Item>()
dataViewModel.allItems.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { items ->
    for (item in mList) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Before Updating: ${item.getDetails()}")
    }
    mList = ArrayList(items)  // update list values
    for (item in mList) {
        Log.i(TAG, "After Updating: ${item.getDetails()}")
    }
})
```

this is for example where i update an item:

```
// current value of subtask in database is arrayListOf(Subtask("Old Subtask", false))
val updatedSubtasks = arrayListOf(Subtask("New Subtask", false))
val item = Item(
    id = id,
    title = title,
    subtasks = updatedSubtasks,
    notes = notes
)
dataViewModel.update(item)
```

When I update an item, with only the subtasks list changed, and Log the data on my list, it shows these results:

```
MyFragment: Before Updating: id: 0
                             title: My Title
                             subtasks: (New Subtask, false)
                             notes: Note

MyFragment: After Updating: id: 0
                            title: My Title
                            subtasks: (New Subtask, false)
                            notes: Note
```

rather than:

```
MyFragment: Before Updating: id: 0
                             title: My Title
                             subtasks: (Old Subtask, false)
                             notes: Note

MyFragment: After Updating: id: 0
                            title: My Title
                            subtasks: (New Subtask, false)
                            notes: Note
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know when do you call update()  method in the ViewModel. But, from your code I could infer the following,

1. When you call update function in `DataViewModel` (hopefully from `MyFragment`), the entity gets updates and that could trigger the `allItems` LiveData.
2. The observer you have on `MyFragment` is triggered the first time when the `init` block gets called. Then you would call `update(item: Item)` in ViewModel that would trigger the LiveData again, and hence the observer in `MyFragment` get its value update again, and that is why you have the same value in `before update` log and `after update log`.
3. To properly understand the situation,

   `mList = ArrayList(items) //the observer is called again here.`
   If you are updating the entity in this line, then the observer will get triggered again with the same value.

Hope I clarified the situation.

Comment: i dont think that my observer is called again at ```mList = ArrayList(items)``` as its not changing anything in my room database

Comment: Oh I thought you are calling update() in ViewModel from there. Well, btw from where do you call the update in ViewModel. As I told the observer will be first triggered from the init  block in ViewModel, then it will be triggered when the update is called if I'm right. When it is called, it will only show the same value in before and after log since you do not alter anything in the lambda block of the observer.

Comment: the log result above is only after i trigger my update function and it does not include the log from it was first called from the init block

Comment: Hey I think I got what's happening here. Since loop is a long running operation, the mList = ArrayList(items) is assigned first somehow. Try Handler.postDelayed({mList.addAll(items)}, 1000). Try this code to see if I'm right.

Comment: i already tried adding delay but it still shows the same results.

Comment: When i change other columns like for example, title, it works fine

Comment: Brother. You are logging both before and after inside that observer lambda only na, then `items` gonna be same only as you are updating the item in mList like, 1) You log items 2) You copy that `items` to mList and log mList. What difference is it gonna have? The observer is triggered only after you update the entity (db).

Comment: This is what happens inside my observer. 1)Log ```mList``` (not ```items```). 2)Set ```mList```'s values to the values of the updated data (```items```) from observer. 3)Log again ```mList```.